What is holding this Jungian question on collective (un)consciousness closed?
A Collective Unconscious That's Alive? was rightly closed to start with for lack of motivation (unreferenced claims).
I started the new member off with some citations and asked them to add to them. Now in my mind, the OP did what is needed and I voted to have the question reopened, yet the question remains closed.
The only reason I can see is the dreaded pseudoscience word again. Is this what is holding the question closed?

I think @ArnonWeinberg may have to jump in here, as they have closed it with the mod hammer. In my opinion though, it does seems a bit like a metapsychology question and frankly I wouldn't mind if it was kept closed. The question itself is nicely referenced and clearly stated, the subject is just a bit, well, metascience, or perhaps Philosophy?

I think it is up to the community to vote for re-opening.  Like @AliceD, I vote to leave it closed.  The citations only provide definitions for (some of the) concepts, but do not substantiate any of the claims made as on-topic, or frame them in a way that can be reasonably answered on this forum.
